# Thread safe memory(key, value) in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, memory, c#-2.0, key-value

I'm working on the .net framework 2.0, I need a Key-Value pair to be stored in memory. I have two threads, one keeps reading the memory and other changes the memory. Is there any equivalent way for ConcurrentDictionary in 2.0? Or any other way to implement this feature?

Comment: What is wrong with a lock.  If you were aware of locks and looking for another way then why did you not put that in the question?

Answer (score 3):

In C# 2.0 you will have to do that manually by implementing locking. You need to create a seperate lock object and before accessing the dictionary you will have to lock that object.

```
   private readonly object lockObject = new object();
   private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> d = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
   lock (lockObject)
    {
        d.Add(key, value);
    }
```

However if you have luxury of moving to latest framework 4.5 you can use [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)

Comment: Say If I have `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` if I'm modifying the list, do I need to lock the list?

Comment: @SatishBejgum I have added an example for you.

Comment: I'm aware of locks, I'm looking at any other way